# split a string into a list and use in If Statement

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a problem with this code. It splits a string into a list and parses through it .I want to do something when I identify a word in the list. I have looked at `IF` statements and although it makes logical sense the code only produces the statement "screen problem advice" regardless of the sentence inputted. I am a bit stumped as to why i cant use  current_word in a conditional statement. Is there something obviously wrong with this?

```
text=str(input("enter your problem"))
words = text.split()

for current_word in words:
    print(current_word)
    if current_word=="screen":
        print("screen problem advice")
    elif current_word=="power":
        print("power_problem advice ")     
    elif current_word=="wifi":
        print("connection_problems advice")
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Please, show an example input-output pair which you find incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code on my machine, it works like it should.

Some short pattern for `if elif elif elif else` is to use some [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) and use the [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.get)-method for lookups.

Some code like this ...

```
if word == "one":
    variable = "11111"
elif word == "two":
    variable = "22222"
elif word == "three":
    variable = "33333"
else:
    variable = "00000"
```

... can be written in some much shorter form:

```
variable = dict(
    one="11111",
    two="22222",
    three="33333"
).get(word, "00000")
```

---

Back to your problem. Here is some sample.
I created a `detect` function which yields all detected advices.
In the `main` function, the advices are just printed out.

Please note the `.lower()` inside `ISSUES.get(word.lower())`, so it catches all variation of "wifi", "Wifi", "WiFi", ...

```
def detect(message):
    ISSUES = dict(
        wifi="network problem_advice",
        power="power problem_advice",
        screen="screen problem_advice"
    )

    for word in message.split():
        issue = ISSUES.get(word.lower())
        if issue:
            yield issue


def main(message):
    [print(issue) for issue in detect(message)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("The screen is very big!")
    main("My power supply is working fine, thanks!")
    main("Wifi reception is very good today!")
```

Further, I deliberately chose some weird examples to point you to some basic problem with your attempt to solve the problem.

A simple string matching won't be enough, as is produces false-positives in this case.
Try to think of some other approach.